# Как обработать событие по клику ссылки на TextView

Tags: android, textview, link, click

имеется `TextView`. При длительном нажатии по тексту запускается функция для копирования части текста

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Была задача повесить на обычный клик вызов диалога. с помощью обычного `setOnClickListener` этого добиться не удалось, потому что из-за `textIsSelectable` приходилось кликать 2 раза. решил эту проблему с помощью `setOnTouchListener`.
Теперь стоит задача сделать переход по ссылкам

в `TextView` добавил строчку

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Вопрос. как мне обработать именно клик по ссылке? Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на текст у меня появлялся диалог с одной информацией, а по клику по ссылке должен появляться другой диалог

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `TextView` параметр `android:linksClickable="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Примените к вашему `TextView` такие параметры:

- `android:onClick="onClick"`
- `tools:linksClickable="true"`

И с помощью обработчика событий обработаете свои нажатия с помощью `OnClickListener`